# How to display Pop-up with Yes and No option from C# code behind without clicking any button and taking response from user

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to display a Pop-up with Yes and No option from C# code behind without clicking any button and I also have to catch the user response in code behind to perform some action in asp.net page.

More specific : I have a textbox, where user will enter some data, on textbox_change event I need to validate the entered data and display a Pop-up to user if that is valid or not, and take user response in the form of Yes/No, based on that, again I have to perform some operation on code behind.

I know to implement it with a button, but my requirement is to display pop-up when user enters data in textbox.

help me guys, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `confirm()` method in javascript.

```
if (confirm("Your Question?")){
    __doPostBack('', 'YES');
} else {
    __doPostBack('', 'NO')
}
```

On the server in `Page_Load()`:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    var result = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Max, But as per my requirement, I have to perform this operation on textBox_change event, not in Page_Load() and also , I have to send user input in pop-up, can you help me with these context ?

Answer (score 0):

you can open a popUp with javascript and upon receiving the user's response make a fetch with the result:

```js
function pop(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  
    let popEle = document.createElement("div");
    popEle.className="pop";
    document.body.appendChild(popEle);
    
    let yes = document.createElement("button");
    yes.innerHTML="YES";
    yes.addEventListener("click",()=>{resolve("YES");});
    popEle.appendChild(yes);
    
    let no = document.createElement("button");
    no.innerHTML="NO";
    no.addEventListener("click",()=>{resolve("NO");});
    popEle.appendChild(no);
    
  });
}
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click",()=>{
  pop().then((res)=>{
    document.querySelector(".pop").remove();
    fetch("https://mydomine.com/myback.net?result="+res);
  })
})
```

```css
.pop{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:#000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">POP</button>
```

Comment: thanks for response, I'm not good in JS, can you plz also tell me how to call your java function? I have tried with this : ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "pop();", true); but it didn't work.. and I also have to send user input in Pop-up (from textbox to Pop-up).

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to create a javascript function:

```
function popup(){
var response=confirm("this data is validate?");
}
```

Then add attribute on your textbox like this :

```
txtsomeData.Attributes.Add("Ontextchange","popup()");
```

Then if you want to send this response to server you can use ajax with WebMethod like :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webmethods.aspx/UpdateData",
            cache: false,
            data: "{ smsCode: " + response+ "}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success)
                {                     

                }
            }
        });
```

And

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateData(string smsCode)
{

}
```

Otherwise you can put it on

> `<asp:hiddenfield>`

using clientId and put your code on popup() JS function after confirm then catch it on your code behind

I hope this will help you.